# how to pass mixin variuable as a path in image directly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, mixins

I have a mixins variable known as imageUrl which I want to pass in image tag directly can someone tell me how to do that I have tried via :src="mixins_name" but it did not work

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the mixin variable inside `data`. Then inherit the mixin.
[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-river-l6j6w?file=/src/mixin.js) example for importing from another file.

```js
var mixin = {
  data: function() {
    return {
      imgURL: "https://picsum.photos/200/200",
    }
  }
}

new Vue({
  mixins: [mixin],
  el: "#app"
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <img :src="imgURL" />
</div>
```

Comment: will this work if mixin is created in another file

Comment: definitely. You just need to import the mixin property.

Comment: import mixins from "@/mixins/global";
export default {
  name: "Layout",
  components: {
    Header,
    Aside,
  },
  mixins: [mixins], I have imported mixins like this but it is not working

Comment: I share a codesandbox link into the answer as well. please check it out